# Fake context creation creates a OpenGL with version 1.1

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to create my own contexts and windows for rendering from scratch. 
(I don't want to use GLFW/SFML or what ever other libraries there is!).

The problem im currently having is that the Fake context I create to load initialize GLEW is only version 1.1 . For some reason it gives me the generic microsoft renderer. I need an accelerated renderer.

My guess is that I do something wrong when I create the pixelformatdescriptor..

**This is how I create the context:**

```
PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd =
{
    sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
    1,
    PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER,    //Flags
    PFD_TYPE_RGBA,            //The kind of framebuffer. RGBA or palette.
    32,                        //Colordepth of the framebuffer.
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    24,                        //Number of bits for the depthbuffer
    8,                        //Number of bits for the stencilbuffer
    0,                        //Number of Aux buffers in the framebuffer.
    PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
    0,
    0, 0, 0
};

int iPixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(m_deviceContext, &pfd);
if(iPixelFormat == 0)
    return false;

error = SetPixelFormat(m_deviceContext, iPixelFormat, &pfd);
if(error != 1)
    return false;

m_context = wglCreateContext(m_deviceContext);
error = wglMakeCurrent(m_deviceContext, m_context);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    return false;
```

If I print the vendor string & renderer string this is what I get:

```
Vendor:   Microsoft CorporationGraphics  
Renderer: GDI Generic
```

**Edit:** I tried to compile in release mode instead(Visual studio 2012) now I get the proper vendor & renderer..

Comment: where is the code you are using to get the vendor string?

Comment: I get the vendor string right after I have initialized GLEW.

Answer (score 0):

If the hardware doesn't support the combination of color, depth, stencil and flags you're supplying, you might be ending up with a software rendered window.

Comment: Do you have a recommended combination? I have been trying everything from the ones recommended on OpenGL official wiki to just random guessing and combinations found and have been working for others..
Could there me anything else wrong, that you can think of? 
My Graphics card should support 4.4 with the drivers I have installed.

Comment: Not really.  I tend to use GLFW for window creation rather than a native API.